# How can I write MySQL query that filters even and odd number from a a single column and return the results in 2 columns as below

Tags: mysql

Input Table

```
Numb
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
```

output table

```
------+------+-
| even | odd |
+------+-----+
|    2 |  1  | 
|    4 |  3  |
|    6 |  5  |  
|    8 |  7  | 
|   10 |  9  |  
|   12 | 11  |  
+------+-----+
```

Comment: what if count of even and odd numbers is different?

Comment: in that case return a null.but in this case its just as it is.all suggestions/answers are welcome

Comment: @Iłya Bursov In that case I suppose we can use a FULL JOIN as we do not know which side is redundant. I tried it and I think it works.

Answer (score 2):

On MySQL 8+, we can use `ROW_NUMBER()` here along with the modulus:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Numb % 2 ORDER BY Numb) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT
    MAX(CASE WHEN Numb % 2 = 0 THEN Numb END) AS even,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Numb % 2 = 1 THEN Numb END) AS odd
FROM cte
GROUP BY rn
ORDER BY 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Tim. I wrote my answer in 5.7. A full UNION is used to warrant no number is left out no matter which side is redundant. Is there a way to simplify that ?

Comment: I think you should refer to one of the other 2 answers to see how to handle your requirement on 5.7.  The row number version is probably simplest, so I suggest upgrading if you expect this requirement often.

Comment: But one of the other 2 answers , which is marked as mysql 8 before, still uses CTE clause which is not supported in 5.7 though.

Answer (score 1):

For MySQL versions prior to 8.0, we can emulate row number using user variables. Supposing the numbers always come in pairs,an inner join is suffice. However, what if the numbers are not in pairs. e.g from 1 to 13, or from 1 to 12 plus 14 . Then an OUTER join should be used to make sure no number is left out. In addition, as we do not know if an odd number or an even number is redundant, we need to use a FULL JOIN which in MySQL's case can be simulated using a UNION between a LEFT JOIN and a RIGHT JOIN. Here is the code written and tested in workbench.

```
select odd,even
from
    (select t1.numb as odd, t2.numb as even 
     from   (select numb,@row_id1:=@row_id1+1 as row_id1
            from test,(select @row_id1:=0) t
            where numb % 2 = 1
            order by numb) t1
            left join
            (select numb,@row_num1:=@row_num1+1 as row_num1
            from test,(select @row_num1:=0) t
            where numb % 2 = 0
            order by numb) t2
     on row_id1=row_num1
    UNION
    select t1.numb as odd, t2.numb as even 
     from   (select numb,@row_id2:=@row_id2+1 as row_id2
            from test,(select @row_id2:=0) t
            where numb % 2 = 1
            order by numb) t1
            right join
            (select numb,@row_num2:=@row_num2+1 as row_num2
            from test,(select @row_num2:=0) t
            where numb % 2 = 0
            order by numb) t2
            on row_id2=row_num2) union_t
order by -odd desc;
```

Two things to note: First of all,as an ORDER BY clause does not work in UNION, we can make the UNION a derived table so the outer layer SELECT statement can effectively apply the ORDER BY clause. Secondly, by default, null is treated as the lowest in ascending order. To make null last in ASC, we can add a minus before the column name and use DESC . Below are some test result:

```
-- result for numbers 1 to 12:
# odd, even
1, 2
3, 4
5, 6
7, 8
9, 10
11, 12

-- result for numbers 1 to 13 (note: workbench displays null as whitespace):
# odd, even
1, 2
3, 4
5, 6
7, 8
9, 10
11, 12
13, 

-- result for numbers 1 to 14 plus 16 18 (note: workbench displays null as whitespace):
# odd, even
1, 2
3, 4
5, 6
7, 8
9, 10
11, 12
13, 14
, 16
, 18
```

Answer (score 0):

before  mysql 8:

```
with v_value as (select even,@rownum:=@rownum+1 as rownum from (select @rownum:=0) a,test b order by even)
select even,(select even from v_value where rownum=c.rownum-1)
  from v_value c
 where mod(even,2)=0;
```

mysql 8:

```
select * from (select even,lag(even) over(order by even asc) as odd from test order by even) a where mod(even,2)=0;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).